# Proving concurrency of point reflections in a triangle

Tags: triangles, reflection, triangle-centres

Let $P$ be a point inside the triangle $\Delta ABC$; $P_a, P_b, P_c$ are reflection of $P$ around $BC, CA, AB$ respectively. What conditions are on $P$ such that $AP_a, BP_b, CP_c$ are concurrent?

I inspired this problem from this problem:
Let $O$ be the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$; $O_a, O_b, O_c$ are reflections of $O$ around $BC, CA, AB$ respectively. Prove that $AO_a, BO_b, CO_c$ are concurrent.

This problem can be solved through considering the intersection of the parallelograms in the diagram. But I thought of generalizing it for any point $P$.

Answer (score 1):

We shall use trilinear coordinates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates and the reference therein.

Let $(p,q,r)$ be a point (in trilinear coordinates, relative to a reference triangle.) The reflection of this point in the Line $BC$ (of the reference triangle) is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
(-p,q+2p \cos(C),r+2p \cos(B)).
\end{eqnarray*}
The equation of the line through this point and $A=(1,0,0)$ is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(q+2p \cos(C))z=(r+2p \cos(B))y.
\end{eqnarray*}
The other $2$ lines can be found similarly and the condition fo their concurrency is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{vmatrix}
0            & r+2p \cos(B) & q+2p \cos(C)  \\
r+2q \cos(A) & 0            & p+2q \cos(C)  \\
q+2r \cos(A) & p+2r \cos(B) & 0             \\
\end{vmatrix}=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a cubic in $p,q$ and $r$ and, strictly speaking, this answers your question.

Similar cubics to this are known see for example https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCpart3.html#X3610.

Note that if $(p,q,r)=(1,1,1)$ (the incenter) then this gives the central point 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{1}{1+2 \cos(A)},\frac{1}{1+2 \cos(A)},\frac{1}{1+2 \cos(A)} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
This is illustrated in the diagram below

[image]

I don't know which of CK's central point it is but I have it coded up as $X14$ ... which it is not !

[image]

For the Circumcenter $(p,q,r)=(\cos(A),\cos(B),\cos(C))$ this construction gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
( \cos(B-C),\cos(C-A),\cos(A-B)).
\end{eqnarray*}
This is illustrated in the diagram below (again I don't know which KFC point this is, although other brands of fried chicken are available.)

[image]

The orthocenter is easy ... it gives the orthocenter.

[image]

These are the only central points, for which, this construction gives concurrence. I did try a few others.